# Program takes (a lot) longer than it should due to a function call that never runs

Tags: c++, boost, include, runtime, boost-ublas

I'm currently running Bayesian Optimization, written in c++. I use a toolbox call Bayesopt from Ruben Martinez-Cantin (http://rmcantin.bitbucket.org/html/). I'm doing my thesis about Bayesian Optimization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization).

I had previously experimented with this toolbox and I have noticed this week that the code is running a lot slower than I remembered. It's worth mentioning that I did write some code that works with this toolbox.

I decided to try to understand why this was happening and I did witness that the code was running much slower than it should.

To try to understand if it was my code's fault or otherwise, I tried an example that doesn't use any of my code.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bayesopt.hpp>


class ExampleMichalewicz: public bayesopt::ContinuousModel
{
public:
  ExampleMichalewicz(bopt_params par);

  double evaluateSample(const vectord& x);
  bool checkReachability(const vectord &query) {return true;};

  void printOptimal();

private:
  double mExp;
};


ExampleMichalewicz::ExampleMichalewicz(bopt_params par):
  ContinuousModel(10,par) 
{
  mExp = 10;
}

double ExampleMichalewicz::evaluateSample(const vectord& x)
{
  size_t dim = x.size();
  double sum = 0.0;

  for(size_t i = 0; i<dim; ++i)
    {
      double frac = x(i)*x(i)*(i+1);
      frac /= M_PI;
      sum += std::sin(x(i)) * std::pow(std::sin(frac),2*mExp);
    }
  return -sum;
}

void ExampleMichalewicz::printOptimal()
{
  std::cout << "Solutions: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "f(x)=-1.8013 (n=2)"<< std::endl;
  std::cout << "f(x)=-4.687658 (n=5)"<< std::endl;
  std::cout << "f(x)=-9.66015 (n=10);" << std::endl;
}

int main(int nargs, char *args[])
{
  bopt_params par = initialize_parameters_to_default();
  par.n_iterations = 20;
  par.n_init_samples = 30;
  par.random_seed = 0;
  par.verbose_level = 1;
  par.noise = 1e-10;
  par.kernel.name        = "kMaternARD5";
  par.crit_name          = "cBEI";
  par.crit_params[0] =   1;
  par.crit_params[1] =   0.1;
  par.n_crit_params  =   2;
  par.epsilon        =   0.0;
  par.force_jump     =   0.000;
  par.verbose_level  =   1;
  par.n_iter_relearn     =     1; // Number of samples before relearn kernel
  par.init_method        =     1; // Sampling method for initial set 1-LHS, 2-Sobol (if available),
  par.l_type             = L_MCMC; // Type of learning for the kernel params


  ExampleMichalewicz michalewicz(par);
  vectord result(10);

  michalewicz.optimize(result);
  std::cout << "Result: " << result << "->" 
      << michalewicz.evaluateSample(result) << std::endl;
  michalewicz.printOptimal();

  return 0;
}
```

If I compile this example alone, the run time is about 23 seconds.

With this cmake file

```
PROJECT ( myDemo )

ADD_EXECUTABLE(myDemo ./main.cpp)

find_package( Boost REQUIRED )
if(Boost_FOUND)
   include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else(Boost_FOUND)
   find_library(Boost boost PATHS /opt/local/lib)
   include_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_PATH})
endif()

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories("../bayesopt/include")
include_directories("../bayesopt/utils")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -Wall -std=c++11 -lpthread -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DNDEBUG -DBOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG")

target_link_libraries(myDemo libbayesopt.a libnlopt.a)
```

Now consider the same main example, but where I add three additional files to my cmake project (without including them in main.cpp). These three files are subpart of all my code.

```
PROJECT ( myDemo )

ADD_EXECUTABLE(myDemo ./iCubSimulator.cpp ./src/DatasetDist.cpp ./src/MeanModelDist.cpp ./src/TGPNode.cpp)

find_package( Boost REQUIRED )
if(Boost_FOUND)
   include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else(Boost_FOUND)
   find_library(Boost boost PATHS /opt/local/lib)
   include_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_PATH})
endif()

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories("../bayesopt/include")
include_directories("../bayesopt/utils")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -Wall -std=c++11 -lpthread -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DNDEBUG -DBOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG")

target_link_libraries(myDemo libbayesopt.a libnlopt.a)
```

This time, the run time is about 3 minutes. This is critical in my work since if I increase `par.n_iterations` it tends to get much worse.

I further arrived at the conclusion that if I comment a line in TGPNode.cpp

```
utils::cholesky_decompose(K,L); (NOTICE THAT THIS LINE IS NEVER CALLED).
```

I get the 23 seconds. This function belongs to a file: ublas_cholesky.hpp, from the bayesopt toolbox.

It is also important to note that the same function is also called within the toolbox code. This line is not commented and it runs during `michalewicz.optimize(result);`.

Does anyone have any ideia why this is happening? It would be a great help if anyone has some insight about the subject.

Greatly appreciated.

Kindly, José Nogueira

Comment: Did you use a debugger (`gdb`)? Did you compile (`g++`) with all warnings & debug info (`-Wall -Wextra -g`)? With optimizations (`-O2 -march=native`)? With profiling (`-pg`) then `gprof`  and/or `oprofile` ?

Comment: Also, I suspect that one of those files has some kind of global static variable whose initialization is taking some time.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: _"I have noticed this week that the code is running a lot slower than I remembered"_ - Can you go back to the version that you used previously?

Answer (score 1):

It's not gonna return.

It's going to infinitely recurse (to a stack overflow).

Here's what the code reads like:

```
bopt_params initialize_parameters_to_default(void)
{
  bayesopt::Parameters par;
  return par.generate_bopt_params();
```

And `generate_bopt_params`:

```
bopt_params Parameters::generate_bopt_params(){
    bopt_params c_params = initialize_parameters_to_default();
```

It looks like someone tried to remove code duplication without actually testing things. At all. You could reinstate the commented out body of the first function

Comment: Mmm. The revision that broke this was [4561d213e4 oct 28](https://bitbucket.org/rmcantin/bayesopt/commits/4561d213e4dd2b6aeb82dfd8153c46b59a421ba2). Looking further since you seem to have had an older version.